# Wirecast crashes when I attempt to authenticate to Youtube account

Tags: youtube, broadcasting, osx, webvideos

Wirecast 4.3.1 (Telestream) on OS X 10.9

After launching Wirecast, I select "Broadcast Settings" --> Authenticate.
Upon selecting my Youtube account and accepting the conditions, Wirecast crashes.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
I tried to re-install the application but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried talking to Wirecast's technical support?  While it probably is still on topic here, I've personally never heard of it and you will probably have better luck talking to people that are familiar with the software.  You might get a response here if someone happens to have used it though.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The first time I opened wirecast it could authenticate, but now it just crashes every time it tries to log in.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. It's very confusing because I had the authentication work earlier in the day. I wonder if Wirecast did something on their end.